# am i supposed to use gas when i a shift gears on a manual?

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, shifting

I have a Chevy s-10 manual, I think the year is 2001?
When i shift gears it usually jumps, should I be using gas while I push in the clutch or before I take my foot off the clutch?
If so how much gas?

Comment: Welcome to mechanics.stackexchange.com!  This sounds like a driving technique question.  I'm afraid these questions aren't on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You say shift gears, so I'm going to assume you're already moving and not starting off from a stop.

You don't need to, and shouldn't use gas when shifting up to a higher gear. A higher gear at any given speed will have the engine turning slower than it was in the lower gear. When you push in the clutch pedal, the clutch will disconnect the engine from the wheels and the engine will start moving toward idle speed. There is a "sweet spot", where the engine speed is matched to the new gear ratio. This is where you should be letting the clutch back out.

If you let the clutch out too soon and the engine is revving too high, you'll feel the vehicle jump forward as the wheels speed up and the engine slows down to match each other at the new ratio. If you wait too long and the engine is revving too low, you'll feel thrown forward in your seat as the wheels slow and the engine revs up to match speed with the new ratio. If you get it just right, you won't feel either, and the vehicle will transition smoothly. This is also easiest on the clutch plate(s), as they don't slip significantly in either direction as the wheels and engine are reconnected.

Shifting down to a lower gear you can add a bit of throttle to speed the engine up to where it needs to be for the lower gear. This is called rev matching.

Every vehicle is slightly different as they have different gear ratios, and practice makes perfect.